# parsing a sentence using Stanford parser with nltk in python

Tags: python, parsing, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp

I am working with a project in python where i need to parse sentences for comparisons and finding similarity between sentences.

I have seen how to parse sentences using stanford parser in java, for the same to do in python,I have downloaded nltk for python.I am new to both python and natural language processing.

I would like to know what are the methods and libraries available with nltk. Any help with possible resources is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use python wrapper for CoreNLP: 
https://github.com/kedz/corenlp